PixelSearch (Multiple same Color issue)
I hope you can help me out on this one.
I'm currently having some trouble with the PixelSearch.
Whenever there is a same multiple color shown, the mouse will only be stuck at the first color and will not move to the next one right after.
The scenario that I want to do is, if there's multiple same color, mouse will move to the first one then left click it and then proceed to the next one and so on until there's no colors left.
Any help is appreciated.
Here is my code below:
toggle := false

F12::
toggle := !toggle
if (toggle) {
    SetTimer, ColorSearch, 100
} else {
    SetTimer, ColorSearch, Off
}
return

ColorSearch:
; Color ID: 0x00FF0F
PixelSearch, Px, Py, 13, 153, 898, 603, 0x00FF0F, 100, Fast

if (ErrorLevel = 0) {
    MouseMove, Px, Py, 1
    Click
    Sleep, 50
} else {
    Sleep, 100
}
return

+::Reload
-::ExitApp

I've tried using CoordMode but to no avail. It only got worse and doesn't search anymore.
